# Блокировки в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, блокировки

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, при каких ситуация (командах) блокируются таблицы или записи! В документациях описаны явные блокировки, а мне нужен список, так сказать перечень операторов sql (команд), когда данные будут блокироваться! Хочу памятку себе сделать (когда есть риск, что где то конкурентная операция будет)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам [таблица](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/15/when-postgresql-blocks/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю это поможет Вам.

Comment: О , спасибо) А во время транзакций -так же все, или даже Select обычный в транзакции, пока commit или Rollback не достигнут конца -будет блокировать?

Comment: @user344622 в самой статье там описано.